# Upgrading hybris from 6.4 to 6.7

Tags: upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud

I am upgrading our b2b website to 6.7 hybris version. We have copied the config and custom folders to new 6.7 setup. We have also copied the data and media. Updated the system.

After server startup the entire WCMS section is not rendering due to which the components on home page do not open.  It gives me the below error on console

```
**WARN  [hybrisHTTP37] [DefaultCMSComponentRendererRegistry] Error processing component tag. currentComponent [TKNavigationBarComponentModel (8796148630588@1)] exception: Missing extension info for given extension name 
Dec 30, 2019 11:12:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing extension info for given extension name 
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:805)
    at com.thyssenkrupp.b2b.global.baseshop.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter$DefaultExtensionAccessor.getInfo(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:272)
    at com.thyssenkrupp.b2b.global.baseshop.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter$DefaultExtensionAccessor.getExtensionDir(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:267)
    at com.thyssenkrupp.b2b.global.baseshop.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter$ResourceAddOnResolver.getExtensionPath(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:113)
    at com.thyssenkrupp.b2b.global.baseshop.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter$ExecutableResourceAddOnResolver.getAddOnFullPathName(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:160)
    at com.thyssenkrupp.b2b.global.baseshop.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:61)**
```

The localextensions.xml is same as  6.4 version. We have also tried querying tables to check if CMSNavigationNodes are present in the DB . In backoffice to the WCMS node is missing.

Can you please suggest what could have gone wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

There are documentation for upgrading. You need a lot of work for every version. For example check [6.6 to 6.7](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a74589c3a81a4a95bf51d87258c0ab15/6.7.0.0/en-US/8be8ff7d866910149618f66c130dab3d.html?q=upgrade) guide (This link private, you need account on SAP).

Comment: I have gone through the upgrade documentation. We fixed build issues and server startup issues after copying custom code into new 6.7 setup.  I did not find any specific steps for WCMS upgrade to 6.7 . Is there anything else that I could be missing ?

Comment: This information is missing in your question, so reply with general upgrade message. Exception said that TKNavigationBarComponentModel has missing attributes. You can check it on db and compare with 6.7 demo system.

Comment: I have tried with the following queries  :-  1.  select * from {TKNavigationBarComponent}  and 2. select * from hybris.cmsnavigationnode   Both of which show results . The error says "missing extension info for given extension name " . I didnt find missing attributes error .

Comment: Jalo codes also working on hac, can you try query as native sql queries?

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example ? I have tried with a few queries on mysql workbench

Comment: @ADIT run 6.7 demo system. Run your above flex query in hac and get native query in next tab. Then use this query in upgraded system (note, you need to change type id).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using

https://answers.sap.com/questions/12766398/missing-extension-info-for-given-extension-name.html

I had to manually change the Resolver file in my custom storefront extension as it was a copy of 6.4 and had the bug mentioned in the above link.